# texture the 3d cube in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

i have ever tried to texture the 3d cube in android using opengl es  according to the example in  c++， but after several times ， the result is disappointed！ 
so i wanna know， who have ever done it before？ may you give me some suggestions？
thanks in advance！

Comment: What kind of crazy punctuation characters are you using?

Comment: oh! i know! i am a rookie in learning English! I am Chinese!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lesson 6 on this page has a well described Android example of showing a textured cube:
http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/

Comment: Thanks! i have finished the function!